# Konnwei kw30 diagnostic equipment

Tags: diagnostics, obd

Just got a konnwei kw830 diagnostic tool I plug it into my car which I know has a fault as I have checked on another system and that comes up with fault key 1 which means my car key has lost its connection to the car which is correct but I plug the kw830 in to have a little play/test and it’s telling me there isn’t a single fault with the car which is incorrect.
Does anyone know if this tool test areas like that ? Or can you tell me what it can do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the Konnwei show it actually negotiating and then talking with the vehicle's computer?

Comment: It has very little option but has the scan button I’m guessing that does it all cause it doesn’t give me a option to delv into separate areas

Comment: When you first plug in the reader and turn the vehicle on (this is generic to every reader I've ever used ... I've not used nor do I know how the Konnwei actually functions), there should be a negotiation phase where it discovers the protocol of the vehicle over the CANBus, then starts talking. If you're not seeing this, I'd suspect the reader is at fault. You could also test the reader on a second vehicle to see if it works there.

Comment: Some readers, and vehicles, are **very** particular about what they will talk to... I made sure that the one I bought talked to my car before purchasing, but I was spending £100... Even if the Konnwei **says** it can do xyz it may not actually work with some vehicles...

Comment: Thanks for your help I’ll plug it into a few vehicles and see if there is a change